# How the web loader reads your CSS to html page

Tags: html, css

I just want to know, if my website(html page) loads the global.css file , does it read the css from top to bottom or the other way around?

example: (if this was my global.css file)

**CSS:**

```
.test {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.test {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

If this was in the css file would it read the bottom styling first or the top one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will apply last style of selector which fits to element of html. It means font size of `<div class="test">` will be 20px. 
But if you define following styles:

```
div.test {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.test {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

`<div class="test">` will apply `font-size: 14px`. This is due to specificity of selectors. First one is more specific.

You can research the [css specificity hierarchy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: Thank you make sense, so you just have to be more specific with your selectors if you want to target the same class with different styles.